# access a different layouts parameter from current activity

Tags: android, android-layout

Suppose my current activity is `Main.java` and I have already declared its layout through `setContentView(R.layout.layout1)` from its `onCreate` method. Now, is it in any way possible for me to access a different layout? For e.g., assuming there is another layout - `layout2` which has `TextView` with id `tv`, then I won't be able to execute the following code from `Main.java` :

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
text.setText("blah blah");
```

Is there any way that I can set `tv`'s value from `Main.java`.

My actual code is the following

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout);
Button button = (Button) findViewById(button);
    button(buttonListener);
Dialog dialog;
```

Inside the listener, I have the following code:

```
TextView dialogTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dialog_title);
        dialogTitle.setText("Email");

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
        builder.setView(customView);            

        dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
```

The problem that I am facing is that `dialog_title` is in dialog.xml and not in `layout.xml`

Comment: why you need to do that?

Comment: I have edited the question to state the reason

Comment: TextView dialogTitle = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title);
        dialogTitle.setText("Email");

Comment: What exactly are you trying ot achieve? Raise a custom AlertDialog?

Comment: please do it after View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);

Comment: but still the way your creating Dialog can be improved http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen Yes, i'm trying to raise a custom dialog and i don't want to hard code its title into the xml as i want to call it from diff activities with different titles

Comment: @DeepakSamuelRajan I tried using your code but it gave me an error on customView

Comment: check my answer below have you used in same format? what is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
        builder.setView(customView);      
TextView dialogTitle = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title); 
dialogTitle.setText("Email");
```

Comment: Its working now. I had commented out the custom view part earlier. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

You can always inflate any XML layout you want at any time:

```
    View layout2 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout2, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Bundles`

**In Activity 1**

```
String your_string = "Hello, World!";
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("The key for this string", your_string );

Intent ActivityToLaunch= new Intent(this, ActivityB.class); 
ActivityToLaunch.putExtras(bundle);
this.startActivity(ActivityToLaunch);
```

**In Activity 2**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout2); //Setup some layout, set to your own

    String content = getIntent().getExtras().getString("The key for this string");
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    text.setText(content);     
}
```

**The thread starter said that he wanted to raise a custom dialog, so here goes the edit**

This is my class which will generate a custom Dialog:

```
public class ErrorDialog {

    TextView msgTextView;
    Button toSettings;
    final Context c;
    Dialog errorDialog;


   /**
     * @param c The Context
     * @param title Title of the Dialog
     * @param msg Message og the Dialog
     * @param textOnButton The text on the button
     */

    public ErrorDialog(final Context c, String title, String msg, String textOnButton) {

        this.c = c;
        errorDialog = new Dialog(c);
        errorDialog.setContentView(R.layout.error_dialog);
        errorDialog.setTitle(title);

        msgTextView = (TextView) errorDialog.findViewById(R.id.errorMSG);
        msgTextView.setText(msg);

        toSettings = (Button) errorDialog.findViewById(R.id.toSettings);
        toSettings.setText(text);
        toSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               //doing operations when the user clicks my button in the dialog. 
            } 
        });

        errorDialog.show();
        errorDialog.setCancelable(true);
    }
}
```

Use this class this way:

```
new ErrorDialog(getApplicationContext(), "My Title", "My Message to the user", "Text on the button");
```

Comment: Is it possible for me to implement the onClickListener from the activity itself as there will be different action for dialogs in different activity.

Comment: the dialog doesn't appear and the log cat shows error on errorDialog.show()

Comment: what type of error? be more specific, we cant guess whats wrong. Its working for me..